# Migration from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012 is getting issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Initially My project had been created with `Visual Studio 2010` for development, later on It was moved to `Visual Studio 2012`. But, It is getting the following issue.

> Error Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the
>   registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed  GiftProcessingService

Comment: So what's your question? Have you checked the SdkToolsPath?

Comment: Are you using express editions?

Comment: In what way are you using al.exe with a C# program?

Comment: I'm using visual studio professional 2012. How can I check SdkToolsPath ?

Comment: @john-saunders, please do let me know how can i check al.exe use?

Comment: Sorry, thought `al.exe` was the assembler. It isn't.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\al.exe -- I can look at al.exe at this location but there wasn't a entry at registry. Registry entry is only available for 3.5 framework.

Comment: @JohnSaunders. I did the changes like my posted answer. It's working now. Is it correct approach ?

Answer (score 2):

It has been solved after made an entry at `registry` at the location of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A`. I have entered the entries as like marked line below.

[image: Registry Capture]